# Replacement for rest in Scheme?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, mit-scheme

Is there a way in which I can make this work without using rest (I tried to put cdr lst wherever rest is but it gives me an error) plus how can I remove the if condition - (if (> N 0) - because all I want display to do is output the list - (list N E)?

```
(define (count lst)
 (if (null? lst) '() 
   (let ((display (lambda (N E) 
                (if (> N 0) (list N E) (list N E))))) 
     (let loop ((rest (cdr lst)) 
                (E (car lst)) 
                (N 1)) 
       (cond ((null? rest) 
              (list (display N E))) 
             ((eq? E (car rest)) 
              (loop (cdr rest) E (+ N 1))) 
             (else 
               (cons (display N E) (loop (cdr rest) (car rest) 1))))))))
```

Comment: Note: Since `display` is a builtin function (prints values) it seems odd to use that name for another purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Note that **all** procedures are just bound to variables in the global scope. 
Example:

```
(let ((rest 5))
  (rest '(1 2 3)))
```

In R6RS and later you should get an exception saying that the number `5` is not a procedure. The reason is that you have overridden the binding  `rest` in this scope and shoudl use the variable `rest` as the binding to `5` and not try to call it as a procedure. In R5RS and earlier the result is undefined since it's not valid Scheme code but most implementations will perhaps have a similar error as R6RS is required to have.

You have done the same with `display` but this time `display` is a procedure that does something else than the global `display`. It's OK in R6RS but it's not ok in R5RS and earlier. An implementation is free to replace it with the global for all supported types. `display` supports **all** types and thus your code might not work in all implementations since it is invalid R5RS.